# What is the meaning of the phrase "going on" ?What part of speech is the phrase "going on"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have found in the novel **The ladykiller** by Martina Cole the following:

> 'She looked 16 going on 25.'

What is the meaning of the phrase **going on**?  
What part of speech is the phrase **going on**?

Comment: Downvoted.  Title does not make any sense, and it looks like you’re trying to make a comment about a different question. Please go make a comment on that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*going*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/going):

> **going** adjective
>
> **going on**
>   : drawing near to : APPROACHING
>   // is six years old *going on* seven

So, *going on* is an adjectival phrase.

In the same way that the phrase is synonymous with the adjective *approaching*:

> She is 16 and she is approaching 25.
>   She is 16 and she is going on 25.
>   She is 16 going on 25.

Comment: The OED doesn't seem to touch this adjectival sense of "going on" and I'm not clear as to why they don't. Seems an omission.

Comment: @WS2 are you looking at the latest version of the OED?  I wouldn't be surprised to find that this sense arose after the first edition was published, and even after the first supplement.  If it's missing from any of their output after [1959](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteen_Going_on_Seventeen) then it is certainly an omission.

Comment: It's in the current online OED but not easy to find: under **go** III.ii.47.1567– "*intransitive*. In the progressive. To approach a specified age, time, or point in time. Also with †in, †of, on, †upon. Originally and chiefly in going on ——:" I think there's a particular (often slightly creepy) nuance that the OED doesn't capture: precocity or sexual attractiveness beyond one's years, in the example.

Comment: @StuartF I obviously missed that.